# Why are these questions highlighted?

Tags: support, questions

Why are the following questions highlighted? Is this a new update? I've never seen it before.

[image: Highlighted questions]

Only two of the questions are highlighted.
Links:

- [Why does "elite" rhyme with "beet" rather than "bite"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/264480/106592)
- [Why is "iron" pronounced "EYE-URN" but not "EYE-RUN"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/264658/106592)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're [watching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312180/295232) the [pronunciation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronunciation) tag. This highlights all questions with those tags on the question list pages.